# A webcomic set in a venice-like city with seemingly Middle Eastern/North African inspired architecture

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

The comic hadn't gotten very far when I first encountered it 5-ish years ago here's what I can remember:

**general features:**

- The story followed an ambassador and his assistant
- They were visiting   a city populated with blue people that I
  believe were said to come    from the depths of the ocean
- the city has architecture with ornate tile-work and lots of gold and clay colors.
- The city seemed to have lots of water features and borrowed from Middle Eastern/North African aesthetics
- I'm 80% sure the art was done digitally
- the art style was sort of aesthetically reminiscent of *Kill 6 Billion demons* and *On a Sunbeam*
- I think it might have been part of a larger project set in the same world

**story beats:**

- It opens with the main character getting out of a boat from a canal and when greeted by his guide (one of the blue people) lets him know he's been here before but years ago
- there's a page toward the beginning where the ambassador's guide takes them to a small restaurant for shrimp skewers and one of the sauces is called "bad idea"
- later (that night or the next morning) the ambassador sneaks out to avoid the guide to do something that I think had to do with the death of someone close to him

I'm sorry if this isn't a super helpful description, unfortunately, like I said, the story hadn't progressed very far when I first read it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is MENA? Good start.

Comment: MENA = middle east / north africa

Comment: Was this a webcomic or a paper one?

Comment: It was a webcomic that I stumbled across years ago. Thanks for helping me on this!

Comment: Do you remember if you read it on the author's website, or possibly a webcomic-specific site like Webtoons, Tapas...?

Comment: Hi, It wasn't on an aggregator site. I think it was the authors site as it linked to more than one comic but it may have been a site dedicated to this one project. Thanks for the question!